# Shopify Nested Block schema

Tags: schema, shopify, shopify-app

I'm wondering if nested block on shopify schema is possible. I search on it but I can't find an answer. Please help me out if anyone knows how to do it.

Here's my schema

```
"blocks": [
  {
    "type": "block_main",
    "name": "Block Main",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "block-name",
        "label": "Quote"
      },
      {
        "type": "url",
        "id": "block-link",
        "label": "URL"
      }
    ],
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "sub_block",
        "name": "Sub Block",
        "settings": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "id": "sub-block-name",
            "label": "Quote"
          },
          {
            "type": "url",
            "id": "sub-block-link",
            "label": "URL"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible. ( sadly )

You will have to use a different logic in order to create nested blocks.

For example you can use a `link_list` field and use the text and URL from the links to populate the information you are looking.

Comment: yeah, that's what I am thinking if I can't solve the nested block. I just want to make sure if nested block could be possible. Thanks @drip great help.

Answer (score 0):

Do this way (This is for example)

```php
{
   "name": "FAQs",
   "settings": [
     {
       "id": "dev-faq-title",
       "type": "text",
       "label": "FAQ Title",
       "default": "Frequently Asked Questions"
     }
   ],
   "blocks":[
     {
       "type": "block-1",
       "name": "Block 1",
       "settings": [
         {
           "type": "text",
           "id": "title",
           "label": "Title"
         },
         {
           "type": "text",
           "id": "accordion-title",
           "label": "Accordion Title"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "type": "block-2",
       "name": "Block 2",
       "settings": [
         {
           "type": "text",
           "id": "title",
           "label": "Title"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
       "type": "block-3",
       "name": "Block 3",
       "settings": [
         {
           "type": "text",
           "id": "title",
           "label": "Title"
         }
       ]
     }
   ],
   "presets": [
   {
     "category": "Text",
     "name": "Top Bar"
   }
 ]

}
```

Answer (score -7):

I think this is nothing but just a way to represent data communication. 
To do this I always create a associative array then convert it into JSON. Look this sample PHP code

//Make associative array

```
$data = array("blocks" => array("type" => "block_main", "name": "Block Main","settings" => array("0" => array("type" => "text", "id": "block-name", "label": "Quote"), [1] => array(type": "url", "id": "block-link", "label": "URL")), "blocks": "type": "sub_block", "name": "Sub Block", "settings": array("0" => array("type": "text", "id": "sub-block-name", "label": "Quote"), "1" => array(type": "url", id": "sub-block-link", "label": "URL"))))
```

//encode array to json

```
$json = json_decode($data)
```

And the same would be happening on server side, When we send Post request. It would also render the nested JSON request to associative array then react on the data.

Comment: this is shopify, php code doesn't apply on it. we are talking about liquid schema and not simple json. have any Ideas on it?

Comment: Not possible in Shopify